# Is there a drawing software that can recognize and convert hand drawn shapes in real time (like ink to shape feature in Office)

Tags: shapes, software-recommendation, drawing-tablet, diagram

I use a Wacom tablet for sketching (diagraming), and I am looking for a software that can aid in that with recognizing and converting hand drawn shapes in real time.

Example in Office (ink to shape feature):

[image]

Comment: Sure illustrator can do this (with shaper tool), procreate can do this (hold still for a while) etc etc...

Answer (score 0):

I also use Wacom for one of my tablets, and I actually used it for the sample I'll show below.

This one is on Adobe Illustrator. The tool is called Shaper Tool.

[image: Using the Shaper Tool on Adobe Illustrator].

The first rectangle I drew was freehand with the paintbrush tool, but then I changed the tool to shaper tool and drew the rectangle again. The second one was the one that got transformed into the actual rectangle, and the one you're probably looking for. However, it is limited to the shapes you can create. For example, if you use the shaper tool and try to draw a star, it will not recognize it.

EDIT: I'm adding another source since you recently mentioned you're looking for an arrow. This one is [AutoDraw](https://www.autodraw.com/) that I just found on Google and tried out.

[Link for showing an example of AutoDraw.](https://i.imgur.com/0kt1VMF.mp4)

AutoDraw includes regular drawing and recognition of shapes and objects such as bicycles. It is a web application, so you don't need to download a software.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work well for diagrams, as it is missing some basic options, like drawing an arrow when connecting two rectangles, for example.

Comment: @circle1452 you may want to edit your question to reflect that information so as to qualify some of what you are doing.

Comment: @circle1452 You can draw straight lines with the Shaper Tool, and just add an arrow head.  No need to actually draw an arrow shape.

Comment: @circle1452 to be totally honest id rather have auto layout than quick drawing for this.